# how to remove all ',' after last word in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to remove all ',' after last word

For example:

DECLARE @X AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'abc,def,gh,,,'

I want this result:

'abc,def,gh'

Comment: Why are you storing these values as a delimited string? This is nothing but painful to work with. Do you always have exactly three values with no more or no less? Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I use sql server 2008 and I don't have exactly three values it might be more or less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To right trim all trailing commas you can use

```
SELECT LEFT(@x, LEN(@x) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(@x)))
```